# Undefined reference to the function 'check' (GCC compilation in MinGW)

Tags: c, gcc, header, include, mingw

I seem to be getting the rookie error where it says, `undefined reference to 'check'`, as shown below:

[image]

This should not be a problem, as I have in fact made a `check.h` and included in `hiker.c`, as shown below:

[image]

Does anybody know the source of this problem? I have just started using MinGW(as I wanted to learn programming C on Windows).

Here is a picture of the main function. I can add the code too if necessary:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Make sure you add `hiker.c` in your Makefile/compilation command. Read the linked duplicate (C++, but C-related issues are also mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `check` function is implemented in a file `check.c`

You must link that file also, because of your `check.h` export the prototype to let the compiler know how the check function is structured, but the linker needs the `check` function code compiled and reachable.

What you need is to compile using a command like this:

```
gcc -Wall hiker.c check.c -o hiker.exe
```

Take also note that linker is giving you another error about `WinMain@16`
This means that you started a `windows application project`, I guess you must change your project to `console project` type.

Comment: I can't seem to find any resources on how to change from a WinMain@16 to a console project. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala In Code::Blocks the option to change this is under: Project -> Properties then select the 'Build Type' tab and look for the 'Type' drop-down box. Make sure to do this with both your Debug and Release versions. BTW I think the best way is to restart creating a new project.

Comment: But I written this project using notepad in a folder. I am not sure why that option came up at all. Why would it be better for me to start a new project?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala ok. In this case I have a new question: is there a main function in your code?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala try renaming it to int WinMain (int, char**)